# How to edit a particular content in a text file using C?

Tags: c, file, file-handling, file-read

Following is **dummyFile.txt**

```
cc:=gcc
file:=good
src:=$(file).c
executable:=$(file).exe

$(executable):$(src)
    $(cc) $(src) -o $(executable)

clean:
    del $(executable)
```

It is a simple kind of `makefile` but it is stored in the text file mentioned above.
Following is `test.c` which will ultimated gentrate `test.exe` when compiled. It has been compiled without warnings and errors so I provide concerning part of the code snippet here.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("dummyFile.txt", "r+");
     if (!fp) {
          printf("Invalid FileName or it does not exist!");
          exit(1);
     }
     int count;
     do {
          //scans the whole line
          fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]c", buffer);
          count = strlen(buffer);
     //skips next char while is newline
          fscanf(fp, "%*c");
    //looking if string is "file:"
          sscanf(buffer, "%[^=]c", t);
          if (!strcasecmp(t, "file:")) {
           char temp[20];
           //Copying the content or simply filename to temp variable
               strncpy(temp, argv[1], strlen(temp));
           //as windows sets \r\n as padding i did increment 2 for count
               count += 2;
          //i am at the next line from "file:" part so this will move my pointer to where "file:" is
               fseek(fp, -count, SEEK_CUR);
          //content overwritten
               fprintf(fp, "file:=%s\n", temp);
        return 0;
          }
     } while (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin));
```

I did :

> ./test newfile

to run the file. And the only motive of this program is to replace that very line (mentioned below) from **dummyFile.txt**

> file:=good

to the following :

> file:=newfile

In fact, the aim is only to modify or replace the part after `file:=` by the given argument while running the program. As length of `file:=good` is less than `file:=newfile`. It should do the job I guess. I was wrong and the changes I see is the following :

```
cc:=gcc
file:=newfile
:=$(file).c
executable:=$(file).exe

$(executable):$(src)
    $(cc) $(src) -o $(executable)

clean:
    del $(executable)
```

Doing a simple analysis. I found the content is overwritten as `file:=good` was changed to `file:=newfile` but from the line3 of original file [`src:=$(file).c`] `src` was missing and turns into [`:=$(file).c`]. 
I want suggestion what to change in my program or my approach. I will follow it strictly.

**EDIT**
Creation of temp_file to copy all lines as it is excluding the intended line would have been the option. (adding intended changes). But I guess there is always a way to my approach.

Comment: You cannot simply **replace** 'n' characters with 'm' characters when 'm' > 'n'... The file is small. Load it (entirely) into a buffer, then write the preamble followed by your new text followed by the post-amble back to the file (overwriting it entirely.) (PS: `scanf()` is the hallmark of novices. Learn to use `fread()`, `fgets()`, ...)

Comment: can you please provide me a demo using `fread()` and loading whole file into a buffer without creating temp_file?

Comment: Sorry... Please refer to the teaching material you've been using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your constraints are, but here is one way to do what was suggested in the comments. I assumed you know what pointers are, since you used one in `FILE *fp`. I also assumed you know how to use `malloc`, but if you don't you can always use a static array that's large enough to fit your file.

The idea is that, since working on files directly is cumbersome, you can copy everything into an array of bytes in memory, and work with it there, then place everything back in the file. You are basically doing operations on strings, the fact that the string comes from a file (and will go back into it) is irrelevant.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("dummyFile.txt", "r+");

char  *arg = argv[1];
size_t arg_length = strlen(arg);

// Get the size of the file
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

size_t extra_space = arg_length;

unsigned char *data = malloc((size + extra_space) * sizeof(unsigned char));
fread(data, size, 1, fp);
unsigned char *at = data;

// Skip the first line ...
while (*at != '\0' && *at != '\n') at += 1;
if (*(at - 1) == '\n' && *at == '\r') at += 1;

// Find the place where you need to write
char match[] = "file:=";
size_t match_length = sizeof(match) - 1;
while (size - (at - data) > match_length && memcmp(at, match, match_length) != 0)
  at += 1;

at += match_length;

// Make space for the string
unsigned char *after = at;
while (!isspace(*after)) after += 1;

size_t original_word_length = after - at;
memmove(at + arg_length, at + original_word_length, size - (at - data));

// Now that there's space, write what you need to write
memcpy(at, arg, arg_length);

// Write everything back into the file
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(data, size + extra_space, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Note 1: This implementation doesn't do any error checking for clarity's sake
Note 2: A few white spaces are added at the end, but you can debug that yourself - don't copy-paste this code, understand it and rewrite it yourself, in a way that YOU are comfortable with.